# Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.

Tags: react-native

[image]

I get this error after building apk with ./gradlew assembleDebug. If I build apk with ./gradlew assembleRelease, I get an error on install app on mobile phone.
When I run same app in virtual device with react-native run-android, app is working fine without any troubles. Any ideas?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0",
    "util": "^0.10.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are the steps i need you to follow to solve this issue.

Delete android folder and do react-native upgrade (not react-native run-android)

create the folder in the following location.

```
your_app/android/app/src/main
```

Perform the following command in root directory. (simply copy and paste the below code)

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js   --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle   --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

**Please note** if you are using index.android.js then replace it in --entry-file.

and lastly

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug
```

Hope this solves your solution.

Comment: Can you tell me whether any bundle files are created inside the assets folder?

Comment: No, I tried to remove android folder at all, generate new android folder with react-native run-android and after that I created again folder assets, generated again apk file, but this didn't resolve problem

Answer (score 20):

**Step 1**: mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

**Step 2**: In package.json i added:

"scripts": {
        "bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res"
    }

**Step 3**: run "npm run bundle" and in the last order

**Step 4**: go in android/ folder and

**Step 5**: run "./gradlew assembleDebug"

Weird bug, and it's still exists until now from 2015!

Comment: Make sure to do this first:

mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

Comment: even in 2018 (＃ﾟДﾟ)

Comment: Yea I don't get that...what is the point of a Get Started for React Native if it doesn't get you started

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart node.

```
ps -ef | grep node | grep -v grep
```

and kill node processes.

It worked for me.