# Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.Make sur your Bundle is packaged correctly

Tags: react-native

When i run `react-native run-android` the apps launch in my devices but gives he following error
[image]

I've tried the solve the problem using the folling links:

[Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563283/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle)

[Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

But,i the problem is not solved.Before i tried to use as described in the official doc from : [Running On Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)
Nothings works for me,even after rebooting the pc which is running Windows 10

Comment: i think you are running the packager in different apps

Comment: No,i'm not running the packager in different apps

Comment: Is your mobile device and your System are on same network? I can see you are on LTE in device

Comment: Okay,the LTE that you see is the wireless connexion shared from mobile hotspot with the pc,so it in the same network

Comment: I've read somewhere that the problem may come from react-native version,mine is :0.56.0 so i should try to downgrade to 0.55.4 because the lastest haq some bugs

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it solves: https://queception.com/question.php?question=10

Answer (score 0):

Try to exit from Node Packager CMD and stop all running CMD. Open new CMD in run as admin. Uninstall app from device. Again go to your project folder and do 'react-native run-android'.

Comment: I've done what you've said and nowi got this `error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `E:\AgamesChristian\react-native\model\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map`

Comment: Under the above error it gives this: `This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.`

Comment: Try  'npm cache clean --force'

Comment: Not always rendering