# Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.rnnpro1/com.rnnpro1.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

Getting build successful but at the end giving error from terminal.
I can't build from Android studio due to system freeze.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 19.967 secs
Running adb -s 2a4ert6817d56123 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on 2a4ert6817d56123 (adb -s 2a4ert6817d56123 shell am start -n com.rnnpro1/com.rnnpro1.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.rnnpro1/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.rnnpro1/com.rnnpro1.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "RNNPro1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

What is the error?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915266/error-type-3-error-activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: @NileshRathod - They recommended to build from android studio, due to system freeze I am not able to build from AS.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you activity initialized in manifest properly

```
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

check build gradle is properly build

build.gradle:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.yourpackage"  
}
}
```

if its not invalidate caches and  rebuild the project

Comment: The above is initialized already.. there is no changes from above.

Comment: Yupp, that also present, done rebuild. it's executing, but got another issue.

Comment: in your mainactiy you trying to open or read files in android?

Comment: I did not get, what you asking !, but checked MainActivity.java, no files call to open/read.

Comment: Its running fine now, after resolve the another bug called assets https://stackoverflow.com/a/48581255/2034750, and your answer is useful +1

Comment: **rebuild the project** is the most useful idea. will you bold it?

Answer (score 0):

`Build > Clean Project` and then `Build > Rebuild project` worked for me. Hope this helps