# The react native app isn't the latest page packaged

Tags: android, react-native

Once the application is developed, I want to package it for release. Install it on my phone and it's not the latest page

react-native:0.58.6
react:16.8.3

cd android && gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: you can delete build folder and rebuild it.. Also Please explain more about your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563283/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

try to run (for RN android)

```
1. react-native start --reset-cache
 2. react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
 3. cd android
 4. gradlew clean
 5. gradlew assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need you to follow to solve this issue.

Delete android folder and do react-native upgrade (not react-native run-android)

create the folder in the following location.

your_app/android/app/src/main
Perform the following command in root directory. (simply copy and paste the below code)

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js   --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle   --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
Please note if you are using index.android.js then replace it in --entry-file.
```

and lastly

```
cd android && ./gradlew installDebug
```

Hope this solves your solution.

[Go to this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563283/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle)